# Maven-Jetty-Plugin. Hot redeploy .war

Tags: java, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I added *maven-jetty-plugin* to my `pom.xml`, and execute goal `jetty:run-war` . All work fine. But when I want hot-redeploy of project, after some changes on source code, I need to repeat goal `package` on my project (I think because I deployed project as .war, not as unassembled webapp).
But when I run `package` goal, I get an error: `Could not copy webapp sources... [C:\..\workspace\PROJECT_NAME\target\PROJECT_NAME-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`]   - It is because files that must be deleted by Maven when executing goal `package` are corrupted(busy) by started Jetty server.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to run jetty as `maven jetty:run`. And just copy compiled files in directory (Or let IDE do it for you). Also you will be able to change static resources without redeploying application

Comment: In project I use also use GWT, so  I can't tell to maven-jetty-plugin to deploy .js files.